# Best way to transplant a Dracaena dragon

Tags: trees, tree-care, transplanting

I would like to know the best way to transplant a Dracaena dragon.

I have 5 and they were planted( 30years ago) very close.  So they are out of space.

My climate is Mediterranean, I'm entering winter now, and the soil is sandy.

Sorry for my English
[image]

Comment: I am more familiar with this plant when it is used indoors.  Can you add a picture so we can get  a better idea of the size and spacing?